# What to append next child node into the parent node using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to append child node into parent node.

Here is the XML. I want to append order_d into order_h if my order_no under order_h is equal to the following order_no in order_h

```
<document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <order>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421424" profoma_po="421425">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="1" order_no="421424" color_code="730" manufacturer="100783">

          <Size_b assoc_id="69398" row_no="0" pct_ratio="PCT" total_pct="100" priority="0" ship_pack="BULK">
            <size_d assoc_id="69398" ship_pack="BULK" ctn_sku="5602060" size_code="XS" alloc_qty="18" plan_pct_ratio="23.5" row_no="0" sort_value="5"/>
          </Size_b>
      </order_d>
    </order_h>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421424" profoma_po="421425">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="3" order_no="421424" color_code="002" manufacturer="100783">
      </order_d>
    </order_h>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421424" profoma_po="421425">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="2" order_no="421424" color_code="257" manufacturer="100783">
      </order_d>
    </order_h>
  </order>
  <order>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421425" profoma_po="421426">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="1" order_no="421425" color_code="730" manufacturer="100783">

      </order_d>
    </order_h>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421425" profoma_po="421426">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="3" order_no="421425" color_code="002" manufacturer="100783">
      </order_d>
    </order_h>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421425" profoma_po="421426">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="2" order_no="421425" color_code="257" manufacturer="100783">
                  </order_d>
    </order_h>
  </order>
  <order>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421426" profoma_po="421427">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="1" order_no="421426" color_code="000" manufacturer="100783">
      </order_d>
    </order_h>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421426" profoma_po="421427">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="3" order_no="421426" color_code="002" manufacturer="100783">
         </order_d>
    </order_h>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421426" profoma_po="421427">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="2" order_no="421426" color_code="450" manufacturer="100783">
                  </order_d>
    </order_h>
  </order>
  <order>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421427" profoma_po="421428">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="1" order_no="421427" color_code="000" manufacturer="100783">
        </order_d>
    </order_h>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421427" profoma_po="421428">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="3" order_no="421427" color_code="002" manufacturer="100783">
      </order_d>
    </order_h>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421427" profoma_po="421428">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="2" order_no="421427" color_code="450" manufacturer="100783">
      </order_d>
    </order_h>
  </order>
</document>
```

and i need output as below

```
<document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <order>
      <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421424" profoma_po="421425">
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="1" order_no="421424" color_code="730" manufacturer="100783"/>
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="3" order_no="421424" color_code="002" manufacturer="100783"/>
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="2" order_no="421424" color_code="257" manufacturer="100783"/>
      </order_h>
   </order>
   <order>
      <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421425" profoma_po="421426">
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="1" order_no="421425" color_code="730" manufacturer="100783"/>
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="3" order_no="421425" color_code="002" manufacturer="100783"/>
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="2" order_no="421425" color_code="257" manufacturer="100783"/>
      </order_h>
   </order>
   <order>
      <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421426" profoma_po="421427">
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="1" order_no="421426" color_code="000" manufacturer="100783"/>
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="3" order_no="421426" color_code="002" manufacturer="100783"/>
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="2" order_no="421426" color_code="450" manufacturer="100783"/>
      </order_h>
   </order>
   <order>
      <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421427" profoma_po="421428">
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="1" order_no="421427" color_code="000" manufacturer="100783"/>
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="3" order_no="421427" color_code="002" manufacturer="100783"/>
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="2" order_no="421427" color_code="450" manufacturer="100783"/>
      </order_h>
   </order>
</document>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="order_h|order_d/node()"/>

 <xsl:template match="order_h[1]">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
    "@*|node()|following-sibling::*/node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be made a well-formed XML document):

```
<document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <order>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421424" profoma_po="421425">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="1" order_no="421424" color_code="730" manufacturer="100783">

          <Size_b assoc_id="69398" row_no="0" pct_ratio="PCT" total_pct="100" priority="0" ship_pack="BULK">
            <size_d assoc_id="69398" ship_pack="BULK" ctn_sku="5602060" size_code="XS" alloc_qty="18" plan_pct_ratio="23.5" row_no="0" sort_value="5"/>
          </Size_b>
      </order_d>
    </order_h>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421424" profoma_po="421425">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="3" order_no="421424" color_code="002" manufacturer="100783">
      </order_d>
    </order_h>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421424" profoma_po="421425">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="2" order_no="421424" color_code="257" manufacturer="100783">
      </order_d>
    </order_h>
  </order>
  <order>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421425" profoma_po="421426">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="1" order_no="421425" color_code="730" manufacturer="100783">

      </order_d>
    </order_h>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421425" profoma_po="421426">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="3" order_no="421425" color_code="002" manufacturer="100783">
      </order_d>
    </order_h>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421425" profoma_po="421426">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="2" order_no="421425" color_code="257" manufacturer="100783">
                  </order_d>
    </order_h>
  </order>
  <order>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421426" profoma_po="421427">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="1" order_no="421426" color_code="000" manufacturer="100783">
      </order_d>
    </order_h>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421426" profoma_po="421427">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="3" order_no="421426" color_code="002" manufacturer="100783">
         </order_d>
    </order_h>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421426" profoma_po="421427">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="2" order_no="421426" color_code="450" manufacturer="100783">
                  </order_d>
    </order_h>
  </order>
  <order>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421427" profoma_po="421428">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="1" order_no="421427" color_code="000" manufacturer="100783">
        </order_d>
    </order_h>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421427" profoma_po="421428">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="3" order_no="421427" color_code="002" manufacturer="100783">
      </order_d>
    </order_h>
    <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421427" profoma_po="421428">
      <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="2" order_no="421427" color_code="450" manufacturer="100783">
      </order_d>
    </order_h>
  </order>
</document>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <order>
      <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421424" profoma_po="421425">
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="1" order_no="421424" color_code="730" manufacturer="100783"/>
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="3" order_no="421424" color_code="002" manufacturer="100783"/>
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="2" order_no="421424" color_code="257" manufacturer="100783"/>
      </order_h>
   </order>
   <order>
      <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421425" profoma_po="421426">
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="1" order_no="421425" color_code="730" manufacturer="100783"/>
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="3" order_no="421425" color_code="002" manufacturer="100783"/>
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000014" line_no="2" order_no="421425" color_code="257" manufacturer="100783"/>
      </order_h>
   </order>
   <order>
      <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421426" profoma_po="421427">
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="1" order_no="421426" color_code="000" manufacturer="100783"/>
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="3" order_no="421426" color_code="002" manufacturer="100783"/>
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="2" order_no="421426" color_code="450" manufacturer="100783"/>
      </order_h>
   </order>
   <order>
      <order_h owner="GD" order_no="421427" profoma_po="421428">
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="1" order_no="421427" color_code="000" manufacturer="100783"/>
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="3" order_no="421427" color_code="002" manufacturer="100783"/>
         <order_d owner="GD" item_no="100000015" line_no="2" order_no="421427" color_code="450" manufacturer="100783"/>
      </order_h>
   </order>
</document>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of and overriding of the **[identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.

Comment: @Dimitre.. thanks alot for beautify code, however my xml is slightly changed and and update above. Could you please let me know what need to modify in the xslt to get the output.Sorry for troubling you. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user1760923, Your question is fully answered. Whenever you "change" the source XML document you actually have a new question. It is recommended not to continuously change a question, but to ask a new question. Therefore, I recommend that you restore the question to its original state and ask a new question. Also, please, *accept* this answer (by clicking the check-mark next to the answer).

Comment: A You suggested i have replaced it to previous xml and marked as answered. Please respond on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534647/appending-child-node-into-the-parent-node.