# Append new child node between existing nodes

Tags: xml, parsing

Can I Know how to append new child node between existing nodes.I am using org.w3c.dom to do parsing

current:

```
<parent node>
<row>a</row>
<row>c</row>
<row>d</row>
<row>e</row>
</Parent node>
```

I want to add new node between a and c

```
<parent node>
<row>a</row>
<row>b</row>
<row>c</row>
<row>d</row>
<row>e</row>
</Parent node>
```

### I tried appending a child under current node but it is getting added at the end

1. Element testNode = doc.createElement("testNode");
2. currentNode.appendChild(testNode);

Comment: What Xml library are you using?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534647/appending-child-node-into-the-parent-node) help?

Answer (score 0):

with jquery you can insert it at nth position as follows:

```
$("<row>f</row>").insertAfter($("ParentNode row:nth-child(2)"));
```